# Module non-existent

Tags: python, plot, module, anomaly-detection

I am currently working with an article on anomaly detetcion. 
I am trying to replicate the import:

```
from workshop_functions.python import plot_confmat
```

but the module is missing.

Thanks!

Comment: can you give us the exact error that you are seeing?

Comment: We will need a little bit more information. First, could you point to the article you are following? As @david-culbreth mentions, the exact error is also important. Did you install any module following this article?